# What is a device used to slice tomatoes with in one motion called?

Tags: equipment, tomatoes

I worked at a restaurant for a month once and they had a device there. It was a rectangular box: you'd put a tomato in it, and there was a handle at the one end you could use to push the tomato against some blades. The tomato would come out the other end in 5 slices.

It was so much more efficient than using a knife, but I don't know what it was called.

I almost want to say it was a tomato slicer, but I never heard anyone call it that.

Comment: If you google/image search for "tomato slicer" you'll find devices with the same functionality - I'd say go for it.

Comment: I'm sure Dr. Seuss covered that at some point....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, believe it or not... it's called a Tomato Slicer, but they are also sometimes referred to as a Tomato Saber. Which is a product name originally from the commercial company [Price Castle](http://www.princecastle.com/).

Although I agree with [Stephie](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/28879/stephie) and [janeylicious](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/4763/janeylicious) just include the additional keyword 'commercial' with your search.

Another option is that you can try the keyword 'Tomato Saber', this should also aid to a successful search.

[image: Tomato Saber]

Comment: That's it exactly!   It looks just like it.

Comment: Do they cost alot?

Answer (score 3):

A tomato slicer! If you're looking to buy one, you may want to add 'commercial' onto a search.

This is what I use at my restaurant: http://vollrath.com/ProductFamily/Food-Preparation-Equipment/Redco-Tomato-Pro.htm